# Upload Speed Issue : HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, upload, httpwebrequest

I am using HttpWebRequest to upload file to certain server, now the problem is I am having speed issues.

I am not able to get the same upload speed as I get with browser (Mozilla Firefox), the speed I am getting is 1/5 of the speed I get from Browser.

Here are my HttpWebRequest object's setting

```
//headers is a NameValueCollection type object,
//Method is a struct { GET, POST, HEAD }

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.UserAgent = headers["User-Agent"];
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Accept = headers["Accept"];
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = AllowRedirect;
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;
```

Some global options that i have kept enabled

```
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 2000;
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 1000;
        ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(false, 0, 0);
```

How i am sending file in chunk...

```
            if (PostMethod == PostType.MultiPart && uploadFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < uploadFiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    string fileParam = uploadFiles.GetKey(i);
                    string tmpFilename = uploadFiles.Get(i);
                    string tmpData =
                    string.Format(
                        "--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n", boundary, fileParam, Path.GetFileName(tmpFilename), MimeType.GetMimeByExtension(Path.GetExtension(tmpFilename)));
                    byte[] tmpBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(tmpData);
                    writer.Write(tmpBytes, 0, tmpBytes.Length);
                    bSent += tmpBytes.Length;

                    arg.Progress = (int)(bSent * 100 / totalBytes);
                    arg.Speed = (bSent / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                    OnProgress(arg);

                    //write the file
                    int fileBytesRead;

                    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(tmpFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
// buffer size = 8192
                    while ((fileBytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) 

                    {
                        writer.Write(buffer, 0, fileBytesRead);
                        bSent += fileBytesRead;

                        int timeNow = Environment.TickCount;
                        if (timeNow - lastTime >= 500)
                        {
                            lastTime = timeNow;
                            arg.Progress = (int)(bSent * 100 / totalBytes);
                            arg.Speed = (bSent / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                            OnProgress(arg);
                        }
                    }

                    tmpBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("\r\n");
                    writer.Write(tmpBytes, 0, tmpBytes.Length);
                    bSent += tmpBytes.Length;

                    arg.Progress = (int)(bSent * 100 / totalBytes);
                    arg.Speed = (bSent / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                    OnProgress(arg);

                }
            }
```

I would be happy to attain even a 75% of browser upload speed.

Comment: Does that browser have any additional AddOns that may be affecting that browsers speed compared to Firefox.  I had a coworker say they uploaded slow in there browser, had em use Windows Default Address navigation instead and it uploaded quick.  Turned out they had some AddOn that siphoned through the data and caused a massive delay.  I'll try and come up with something better then that though.

Comment: @Greg - no, just 2 plugins i have, Live HTTP Headers, and TamperData!

Comment: Is there some reason WebClient.UploadFile is not being used?

Comment: @Dan-o - yes.... some of the HTTP request differ from normal format!

Comment: Why KeepAlive false? why SetTcpKeepAlive? why AllowWriteStreamBuffering false? what is the writer variable?

Comment: What kind of data are you uploading? Any chances that the browser (Firefox) and WebServer are using [http compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)? Probably your code isn't.

Comment: @publicgk - no, compressing, and above that multi-part post dont needs compression thing, the kind of data i am uploading are file between 2 gb to 50 GB

Comment: How does this upload perform in different browsers?

Comment: Why are you doing a file upload using HTTPWebRequest? Need to imitate a browser or something?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ShannonCook - yes, partially with `HttpWebRequest`, but i ended up writing a simple http wrapper with `System.Net.Socket`

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer by searching this site.  It appears to be a duplicate of [".NET HttpWebRequest Speed versus Browser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048408/net-httpwebrequest-speed-versus-browser).

From the answers posted there:

"The first time you request a page, .net tries to detect proxy settings. The solution is to pass in an empty WebProxy object. This way it just connects to remote server instead of autodetecting the proxy server." - [Markos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233027/markos)

Try adding

```
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

Comment: i have set `request.Proxy = null`, additionally the problem is with upload speed, i have to upload big files say 2 GB  file, with mozilla firefox its almost 3x faster!

Comment: problem is the Upload speed, if the connection delays by few microsecs that is ok to me, but i need a better upload speed!

Comment: Sorry that didn't work for you.  I'll try to recreate the issue myself.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the ServicePointManager values at their defaults?  The DefaultConnectionLimit, MaxServicePointIdleTime, and MaxServicePoints may be limiting your throughput.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666268/httpwebrequest-and-httpwebresponse-ideal-async-buffer-sizes

Comment: yes already tried that!

Comment: I've been unable to recreate your results.  I'm getting transfers equal or better than in-browser with my tests.  Perhaps more information could be added to the question to help find a solution.

Comment: can you tell me how big file you are trying?

Comment: the problem arise when file is sent in multiple chunk.

Comment: Any chance for you to try WCF. We had similar issue and resolved by introducing WCF service to upload file in chunks.

Comment: I tried using a randomly generated 512 MB file.  You said earlier, "some of the HTTP requests differ from normal format."  Can you elaborate?  Also, what other buffer sizes have you tried?

Comment: i tried buffer size of 8192, 16384 & 32768!

Comment: it differs as it write the file as post data without any additionally thing!

Comment: I'm stumped.  The answer posted by Infinite Possibilities seems the most likely.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

1. You're defeating the purpose of TCP/IP stacks by chunking. TCP/IP is designed to handle near asynchronous transmission of data. It will do its own chunking and continue to send chunks until it is finished or reaches its maximum number of unacknowledged chunks. If the max number of chunks is reached, it will wait for an ACK(acknowledge) to continue - similar to a semaphore ideology expect the releases can be "stacked", AKA a single ACK contains the last point it received and can "release"/acknowledge multiple chunk packets) - or the request times out.

   By chunking it yourself, each chunk has to be fully acknowledged to send anymore data so you're increasing your overhead. You are still using the same connection, but essentially making multiple separate requests. In addition, if the TCP/IP chunk size is not a divisor of you chunk size (YOUR_CHUNK_SIZE % TCP_IP_CHUNK_SIZE != 0) you are leaving a lingering TCP/IP chunk that has to timeout and resolve to a pseudo ACK; it gets acknowledged the next time it can in the next chunk.
  2.

> Another option that can have an impact on performance is the use of the [UseNagleAlgorithm property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.usenaglealgorithm%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). When this property is set to **true**, TCP/IP will try to use the TCP Nagle algorithm for HTTP connections. The Nagle algorithm aggregates data when sending TCP packets. It accumulates sequences of small messages into larger TCP packets before the data is sent over the network. Using the Nagle algorithm can optimize the use of network resources, although in some situations performance can also be degraded. Generally for constant high-volume throughput, a performance improvement is realized using the Nagle algorithm. But for smaller throughput applications, degradation in performance may be seen.
>
> An application doesn't normally need to change the default value for
>   the [UseNagleAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.usenaglealgorithm%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property which is set to **true**. However, if an
>   application is using low-latency connections, it may help to set this
>   property to **false**.

From MSDN: [HttpWebRequest Class (System.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is various option using that we can increase uploading speed :-

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/440179-how-speed-up-file-upload-2-0-a

use this in config file for large file:---

Write this in web config  system.web>

***httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"***

this may be help for find solution in IIS 7.0

Write this in web config  system.web>httpModules

```
**add name="ITHitPutUploadProgressAndResumeModule" type="ITHit.WebDAV.Server.ResumableUpload.PutUploadProgressAndResumeModule, ITHit.WebDAV.Server"**
```

Comment: its not a web app, its `WinForm`